# Razorpay integration in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, razorpay

I am trying to integrate the Razorpay payment gateway from my Xamarin App. For which I have added RezaorPay Dll on the application and pass the needed parameters but problem is that it does not redirect me to the webview.

I am sharing my code here. Kindly go through it and let me know, what are the changes required?

```
            Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            input.Add("amount", 100); // this amount should be same as transaction amount
            input.Add("currency", "INR");
            input.Add("receipt", "12121");
            input.Add("payment_capture", 1);

            string key = "******";
            string secret = "******";

            RazorpayClient client = new RazorpayClient(key, secret);

            Razorpay.Api.Order order = client.Order.Create(input);
            orderId = order["id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below code to show you view

```
Activity activity = this;  
try {  
    JSONObject options = new JSONObject();  
    options.Put("description", "My Sample Payment activity");  
    options.Put("order_id", "order_EAMgUyLXrMfbmL");  
    options.Put("currency", "INR");  
    options.Put("amount", "100");  
    checkOut.Open(activity, options);  
} catch (Exception ex) {  
    Console.WriteLine("error in payment");  
}
```

Callback methods.

```
public void OnPaymentError(int p0, string p1, PaymentData p2) {  
    Console.WriteLine("error in payment");  
}  
public void OnPaymentSuccess(string p0, PaymentData p1) {  
    Console.WriteLine("success");  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use your given code but I am not able to access the checkOut class which you mentioned above. As I checked and found Razorpay is not providing any checkout class or function for Xamarin. so, how can I get it?

Comment: for xamarin forms you need create a binding library of checkout aar file